# Sitecore Commerce Server - get full order list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, microsoft-commerce-server

I have a task: create a custom admin page in Sitecore to show FULL order history. I found a way to get order history per visitor, but couldn't find anything to get a full list of orders.

To get an order list per visitor we can use method

```
public virtual GetVisitorOrdersResult GetVisitorOrders(GetVisitorOrdersRequest request);
```

from class `Sitecore.Commerce.Services.Orders.OrderServiceProvider`
and assembly: `Sitecore.Commerce`

I think we can get all users and after that get orders for each user. However, I don't think that it is a best way to solve the task. I will appreciate if you advice any other way to get all data.

Thank you in advance for the help.

P.S. I am using Sitecore 8.

Comment: I think your answer may be in this function. Just a guess. https://github.com/Sitecore/Reference-Storefront/blob/1ba2990d08dc705ad0475975c01cd7803687426c/Storefront/CS/CSF/Managers/OrderManager.cs#L156

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I looked at the Storefront example. I needed a different function and I think I found it(please look at my answer below if you are interested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution

```
var contextManager = new CommerceServerContextManager();  //using Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer;
OrderManagementContext orderManagementContext = contextManager.OrderManagementContext;
var orderManager = orderManagementContext.PurchaseOrderManager;

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DataSet searchableProperties = orderManager.GetSearchableProperties(culture.ToString());
SearchClauseFactory searchClauseFactory = orderManager.GetSearchClauseFactory(searchableProperties, "PurchaseOrder"); //using CommerceServer.Core; Assembly CommerceServer.Core.CrossTier
SearchClause searchClause = searchClauseFactory.CreateClause(ExplicitComparisonOperator.OnOrAfter, "Created", StartDate);

SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions();
options.SetPaging(10, 1);

var result = orderManager.SearchPurchaseOrders(searchClause, options);
```

Might be useful for somebody else.